# PATCH Async requests with Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class

Tags: c#, http, patch, dotnet-httpclient

I need to do a `PATCH` request with the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` class and there is no official documentation on how to do it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I found how to do a "custom" `PATCH` request with the previous `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class [here](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/patch-support-in-httpclient/), and then fiddled with until I made it work in the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` class, like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, IHttpContent iContent) {
    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri) {
        Content = iContent
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    // In case you want to set a timeout
    //CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(60).Token;

    try {
         response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
         // If you want to use the timeout you set
         //response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cancellationToken);
    } catch(TaskCanceledException e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: instead of
```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
```
use
```
var response = default(HttpResponseMessage);
```

Comment: You might want to use ` .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` after the `SendAsync` this way:  `response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);;` in order to escape potential issues with hanging request.

Answer (score 62):

**Update:** See [SSX-SL33PY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450277/448357) below for an even better solution, that does the same thing.

You can write the very same method as extension method, so you can invoke it directly on the HttpClient object:

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
   public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, HttpContent iContent)
   {
       var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
       {
           Content = iContent
       };

       HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
       try
       {
           response = await client.SendAsync(request);
       }
       catch (TaskCanceledException e)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
       }

       return response;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var responseMessage = await httpClient.PatchAsync(new Uri("testUri"), httpContent);
```

Comment: how do you pass the content?

Comment: You see the second parameter? Try something like this: `HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("Your JSON-String", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` for String-Contents.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but PATCH method means you only modify specific data within the JSON. How do you modify, let's say, just the name of a product? If by "Your JSON-String" you mean the whole JSON, then I'm confused. I tried to add a single property like `HttpContent content = new StringContent("{\"name\":\"John Doe\"", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` but the content isn't added to the request.

Comment: You might want to use ` .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` after the `SendAsync` this way:  `response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);;` in order to escape potential issues with hanging request.

Answer (score 43):

I'd like to extend on @alexander-pacha's answer and suggest adding following extension class somewhere in a common library. Wether this be a common library for a project / client / framework/... is something you'll have to make out on your own.

```
    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Send a PATCH request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1"/>.The task object representing the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="client">The instantiated Http Client <see cref="HttpClient"/></param>
        /// <param name="requestUri">The Uri the request is sent to.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The HTTP request content sent to the server.</param>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="client"/> was null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="requestUri"/> was null.</exception>
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, HttpContent content)
        {
            return client.PatchAsync(CreateUri(requestUri), content);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a PATCH request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1"/>.The task object representing the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="client">The instantiated Http Client <see cref="HttpClient"/></param>
        /// <param name="requestUri">The Uri the request is sent to.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The HTTP request content sent to the server.</param>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="client"/> was null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="requestUri"/> was null.</exception>
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, HttpContent content)
        {
            return client.PatchAsync(requestUri, content, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Send a PATCH request with a cancellation token as an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1"/>.The task object representing the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="client">The instantiated Http Client <see cref="HttpClient"/></param>
        /// <param name="requestUri">The Uri the request is sent to.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The HTTP request content sent to the server.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="client"/> was null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="requestUri"/> was null.</exception>
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return client.PatchAsync(CreateUri(requestUri), content, cancellationToken);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a PATCH request with a cancellation token as an asynchronous operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1"/>.The task object representing the asynchronous operation.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="client">The instantiated Http Client <see cref="HttpClient"/></param>
        /// <param name="requestUri">The Uri the request is sent to.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The HTTP request content sent to the server.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="client"/> was null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="requestUri"/> was null.</exception>
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUri)
            {
                Content = content
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static Uri CreateUri(string uri)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri) ? null : new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
    }
```

This way you're not awaiting and holding up execution in some static extension class, but you handle that as if you were really doing a `PostAsync` or a `PutAsync` call. You also have the same overloads at your disposal and you're letting the `HttpClient` handle everything it was designed to handle.

Comment: This looks great. You should consider creating a Pull-Request with it on Github in the official repository of the .NET Framework, as they welcome contributions: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs

Comment: Edit: Someone beat me to it, it has been added to the repo you linked by someone else.

Answer (score 7):

For it to work you need to pass the content like that:

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("Your JSON-String", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Static class (I have created as Extention)

```
public static class Extention
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient 
    client, string requestUri, T value)
    {
        var content = new ObjectContent<T>(value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUri) 
        { Content = content };

        return client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Step 2 : Call this method in your api request

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = Extention.PatchAsJsonAsync<UserUpdateAPIModel>(client, "https://api.go1.com/v2/users/5886043", data);
```

Problem solved , here if it is common url , then you can do it with your practice