# Using the octokit.net library to update a submodule commit sha in github

Tags: c#, git, github, octokit.net

I am currently trying to update a submodule's commit id automatically when another project has certain files changed. I have a .net webhook and I'm using the octokit.net library.

I can see in the github documentation (https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) there is a submodule option when creating a new tree that allows you to add a commit and path, but I can't get it to work. Octokit also has a submodule type for the NewTreeItem/TreeItem objects but no examples or documentation.

My current code is here - currently I'm passing the commit sha in as the sha parameter, but I can see this is wrong, I need to create a commit on that repo and use that sha, I just don't know how to do that before the tree is created and there isn't any documentation that I can find:

```
    public static async Task UpdateSubmoduleInBranch(string repo, string branchName, string submodulePath, string sha, string commitComment, GitHubClient github = null)
    {
        //hoping this will update the sha of a submodule

        // url encode branch name for github operations
        branchName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(branchName);

        if (github == null) github = GetClient();

        var repoId = (await github.Repository.Get(Settings.GitHub.OrgName, repo)).Id;

        RepositoriesClient rClient = new RepositoriesClient(new ApiConnection(github.Connection));

        var branch = await rClient.Branch.Get(repoId, branchName);

        var tree = await github.Git.Tree.Get(repoId, branchName);

        var newTree = new NewTree { BaseTree = tree.Sha };
        newTree.Tree.Add(new NewTreeItem
        {
            Mode = Octokit.FileMode.Submodule,
            Path = submodulePath,
            Type = TreeType.Commit,
            Sha = sha
        });

        var createdTree = await github.Git.Tree.Create(repoId, newTree);

        var newCommit = new NewCommit(commitComment, createdTree.Sha, new[] { branch.Commit.Sha });
        newCommit.Committer = Settings.GitHub.Committer;

        var createdCommit = await github.Git.Commit.Create(Settings.GitHub.OrgName, Settings.GitHub.AppName, newCommit);

        var updateRef = new ReferenceUpdate(createdCommit.Sha, false);
        await github.Git.Reference.Update(repoId, "heads/" + branchName, updateRef);
    }
```

**Edit**

In case anyone else is looking for this, I resolved the issue - the octokit api does *not* support this action, even if it looks like it does.

In addition to the PatchAsync method found at [PATCH Async requests with Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218764/patch-async-requests-with-windows-web-http-httpclient-class), the following code worked for me:

```
    public static async Task UpdateSubmoduleInBranch(string repo, string branchName, string submodulePath, string sha, string commitComment)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //these headers authenticate with github, useragent is required.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Settings.GitHub.AuthToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("mathspathway-environment-manager", "v1.0"));

                var committer = Settings.GitHub.Committer;

                //get the branch, and collect the sha of the current commit
                var branchResponse = await client.GetAsync($"{Settings.GitHub.ApiUrl}/repos/{Settings.GitHub.OrgName}/{repo}/branches/{branchName}");
                JToken branchResult = JToken.Parse(await branchResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                var currentCommitSha = branchResult["commit"].Value<string>("sha");

                //create the new tree, with the mode of 160000 (submodule mode) and type of commit, and the sha of the other 
                //repository's commit that you want to update the submodule to, and the base tree of the current commit on this repo
                var newTreeObj = new
                {
                    base_tree = currentCommitSha,
                    tree = new List<Object> { new { path = submodulePath, mode= "160000", type = "commit", sha = sha}
            }
                };

                HttpContent treeHttpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newTreeObj));
                var treeResponse = await client.PostAsync($"{Settings.GitHub.ApiUrl}/repos/{Settings.GitHub.OrgName}/{repo}/git/trees", treeHttpContent);
                var treeResponseContent = JToken.Parse(await treeResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                var treeSha = treeResponseContent.Value<string>("sha");


                //Create a new commit based on the tree we just created, with the parent of the current commit on the branch
                var newCommitObj = new
                {
                    message = commitComment,
                    author = new { name = committer.Name, email = committer.Email, date = committer.Date },
                    parents = new[] { currentCommitSha },
                    tree = treeSha
                };
                HttpContent newCommitContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newCommitObj));
                var commitResponse = await client.PostAsync($"{Settings.GitHub.ApiUrl}/repos/{Settings.GitHub.OrgName}/{repo}/git/commits", newCommitContent);
                var commitResponseContent = JToken.Parse(await commitResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                var commitSha = commitResponseContent.Value<string>("sha");



                //create an update reference object, and update the branch's head commit reference to the new commit
                var updateRefObject = new { sha = commitSha, force = false };
                HttpContent updateRefContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateRefObject));
                var updateRefResponse = await client.PatchAsync($"{Settings.GitHub.ApiUrl}/repos/{Settings.GitHub.OrgName}/{repo}/git/refs/heads/{branchName}", updateRefContent);

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error occurred updating submodule: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you remember what error it was giving you? I was able to get this to work almost exactly as you describe your original code. The only difference I had was, in the `new NewCommit` line, I used the overload that takes a single SHA as the last param instead of the enumerable one. [Gist](https://github.com/patridge/GitPlayground/blob/dae3bb0b053c4465701341477ebfbeb5bb6af9a0/GitPlayground/Program.cs#L161-L176)

Comment: I don't remember the exact error - interesting, I might have been a lot closer than I thought. I got a reply from github support that said it wasn't supported and I had to use the git data api.

From the email:   
  
> Repo Contents API doesn't support updating submodules:  
> https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/  
> However, you should be able to use the low-level Git Data API to update a submodule.

Comment: It could have even been a bug in the framework at the time that is now fixed. Either way, at least you found something that worked at the time.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to accomplish roughly the same goal, but via a separate user's submitting a pull request, I gave your original code a shot with some minor changes. The result was that it worked perfectly with Octokit.net.

#### Extracted sample code

```cs
var submoduleRepoId = (await gitHubClient.Repository.Get(submoduleRepoOwnerName, submoduleRepoName)).Id;
var submoduleRepoBranchLatestSha = (await gitHubClient.Git.Tree.Get(submoduleRepoId, submoduleRepoBranchName)).Sha;
…
var updateParentTree = new NewTree { BaseTree = parentRepoBranchLatestSha };
updateParentTree.Tree.Add(new NewTreeItem
{
    Mode = FileMode.Submodule,
    Sha = submoduleRepoBranchLatestSha,
    Path = pathToSubmoduleInParentRepo,
    Type = TreeType.Commit,
});
var newParentTree = await gitHubClient.Git.Tree.Create(pullRequestOwnerForkRepoId, updateParentTree);
var commitMessage = $"Bump to {submoduleOwnerName}/{submoduleRepoName}@{submoduleCommitHash}";
var newCommit = new NewCommit(commitMessage, newParentTree.Sha, parentBranchLatestSha);
var pullRequestBranchRef = $"heads/{pullRequestBranchName}";
var commit = await gitHubClient.Git.Commit.Create(pullRequestOwnerName, parentRepoName, newCommit);
var await gitHubClient.Git.Reference.Update(pullRequestOwnerForkRepoId, pullRequestBranchRef, new ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha));
```

[Full sample code](https://github.com/patridge/SubmoduleUpdateGenerator/blob/0e68a692587c33f1e994b40f3580e52229fe53e6/SubmoduleUpdateGenerator/Program.cs#L183)

At this point, there are only a few potential differences I can see.

- I definitely do not `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` my branch name (Octokit must be doing any needed encoding for me)
- I am committing to a separate user's branch on their own fork

It could be those differences were sufficient or maybe a bug has been worked out that was around when you were attempting the same thing.