# PATCH request to the service doesn't work within my C# application, but works in Fiddler

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am currently developing a REST-ful C# application that works with an external service. I have gotten basic 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', and 'DELETE' requests to work, however whenever I attempt to send a PATCH request to the same service, it does not work. I get a 200 message (meaning it was successful), but doing a GET on the subject that I am trying to attempt the PATCH request on shows that no change occurred.

Additionally, whenever I use Fiddler to form PATCH requests, using the same URL and content string, it works as expected.

I am attempting to ensure that it isn't something I am doing wrong in regards to how I am sending the HTTP request.

My call that interacts with all of the different above REST functions is as follows:

```
    public async Task<T> GetResultFromService<T>(string requesttype, string url, string request = "")
    {
        HttpRequestMessage message;
        switch (requesttype)
        {
            case "Post":
                message = PostRequest(url, client, request);
                break;
            case "Put":
                message = PutRequest(url, client, request);
                break;
            case "Patch":
                message = PatchRequest(url, client, request);
                break;
            case "Delete":
                message = DeleteRequest(url, client);
                break;
            default:
                message = GetRequest(url, client);
                break;
        }

        var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return IModel.FromJson<T>(responseString);
    }
```

My function for forming the PATCH request:

```
    public HttpRequestMessage PatchRequest(string url, HttpClient client, string content = "")
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url);

        return request;
    }
```

Adding a GET request for comparison:

```
    public HttpRequestMessage GetRequest(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        return request;
    }
```

And my Httpclient code (if it is at all relevant...):

```
        var proxy = new WebProxy
        {
            Address = ServerEnv.ProxyUri
        };
        var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = proxy,
            UseProxy = true
        };

        client = new HttpClient(httpHandler, true);
```

Any sort of direction you can point me in would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

edit: I realized my mistake due to the answerer's reply. Basically I accidentally left out the body on my PATCH, but it was on my POST and PUT and I had overlooked that detail. POST code for detail:

```
    public HttpRequestMessage PostRequest(string url, HttpClient client, string content)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(content,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")
        };

        return request;
    }
```

and the revised PATCH:

```
    public HttpRequestMessage PatchRequest(string url, HttpClient client, string content = "")
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(content,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")
        };

        return request;
    }
```

If any lesson can be learned from this, it would be that you should double and triple check copy and pasted code. Thanks again!

Comment: Please show us the Fiddler request that did work.

Comment: Why do you have a `content` parameter that isn't used?

Comment: requesttype fallback on get method as it is default choice please print/debug your code

Comment: @steve16351 don't think so - [`new HttpMethod("PATCH")`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpPatchAttribute.cs#L15)

Comment: To answer @mjwills, that was the part of the issue that wasn't clicking with my brain at 4:30 yesterday. I should have been using the content!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH` requests are missing a body. How should the service handing the request know what you want to change on the resource? You need to set the `Content` property on the `HttpRequestMessage`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26218765/18044) for an example.